# Formatting a number with correct decimal scale

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I need to format a number with scale of 2 decimal places. The original number may be a whole number or a number with three decimal places. However the result should be formatted to have commas and also two decimal places always regardless of whether the original number is whole number or having decimal places.

1. When original num  = 56565656.342 ==> I need 56,565,656.34
2. When original num  = 56565656 ==> I need 56,565,656.00
3. When original num  = 56565656.7 ==> I need 56,565,656.70

I am using the following code which is formatting the code but its failing to add the two decimal places in the above 2 & 3 cases.

```
String originalNumber = "56565656.7";
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(originalNumber).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
String formattedNumber = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(b);
```

Please let me know if there is any way to accomplish this in efficeint way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

Alternatively you can [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,int)) method from the BigDecimal Class.

```java
BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal("56565656.342");
BigDecimal bg2 = new BigDecimal("56565656.00");
BigDecimal bg3 = new BigDecimal("56565656.70");

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
System.out.println(df.format(bg1.doubleValue()));
System.out.println(df.format(bg2.doubleValue()));
System.out.println(df.format(bg3.doubleValue()));

System.out.println(bg1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
System.out.println(bg2.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
System.out.println(bg3.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Yields:

```
56,565,656.34
56,565,656.00
56,565,656.70
56565656.34
56565656.00
56565656.70
```

EDIT: Also forgot to mention: If you are after precision, I would recommend you use the `setScale` method, using the `.doubleValue()` method will yield a `double` which can cause loss of precision.

Comment: If you use the following when constructing the DecimalFormat `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");` the first three println will print with 2 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `NumberFormat` and specify the fraction digits, and rounding method, to print :

```
String [] originalNumbers = new String[] {
   "56565656.342",
   "56565656.7",
   "56565656"
};

NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getInstance();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

for (String number : originalNumbers) {
   String formattedNumber = df.format(new BigDecimal(number));

   System.out.println(formattedNumber);
}
```

Will print

```
56,565,656.34
56,565,656.70
56,565,656.00
```

** **Edit** **

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

Will produce the exact same result with the given code above.

Answer (score -2):

DecimalFormat class would do it for you.... You will have to specify appropriate format.

Comment: Your answer was far too vague. If you spend only a couple of lines explaining something and if you do not provide a single line of code, you can be sure that the answer is not going to be adequate.