# Format Bigdecimal in Java

Tags: java, format, bigdecimal

I would like to format a BigDecimal value according to the following rules:

```
25 => 25
25,1 => 25,10
25,10 => 25,10
25,12 = > 25,12
```

I have searched the forums but not found a matching question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269045/format-a-bigdecimal-as-string-with-max-2-decimal-digits-removing-0-on-decimal-p), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858485/formatting-a-number-with-correct-decimal-scale)) and I have looked at the javadoc for [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) without understanding how to do this.

EDIT:
Today I do:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat02 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
currencyFormat02.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
currencyFormat02.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
currencyFormat02.setGroupingUsed(false);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("25 or 25,1 or 25,10 or 25,12");
String x =currencyFormat02.format(bd);
```

x should print as above but does not.

Comment: Examples are great, but you also need to specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You still haven't described your goal.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, this a solution! Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most efficient but you could try something like this:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal ex1 = new BigDecimal("25");
    BigDecimal ex2 = new BigDecimal("25.1");
    BigDecimal ex3 = new BigDecimal("25.10");
    BigDecimal ex4 = new BigDecimal("25.12");
    printCustomBigDecimalFormat(ex1);
    printCustomBigDecimalFormat(ex2);
    printCustomBigDecimalFormat(ex3);
    printCustomBigDecimalFormat(ex4);
  }

  public static void printCustomBigDecimalFormat(BigDecimal bd) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00", symbols);
    if(containsDecimalPoint(bd)) {
      System.out.println(df.format(bd));
    } else {
      System.out.println(bd);
    }
  }

  private static boolean containsDecimalPoint(BigDecimal bd) {
    return bd.toString().contains(".");
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
25
25,10
25,10
25,12
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fbbz/1)

Comment: I like the [mcve] aspect in your example!

Answer (score 1):

You then need to distinguish between BigDecimal values that represent "whole numbers"; and those that do not.

Something like:

```
BigDecimal someNumber = ...
if (someNumber.toBigIntegerExact()) {
 // go for the 25 kind of formatting
} else {
 // go for the 25.xx kind of formatting
```

The "25.xx" formatting is nicely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515640/how-to-display-a-number-with-always-2-decimal-points-using-bigdecimal) ( or in the other answer by Leonardo )

Answer (score 0):

To format BigDecimal with NumberFormat, you need to set Locale first, try something like this:

```
String strToFormat = "25.10";
Locale loc = new Locale("en","US");

DecimalFormat numFormat = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
numFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal yourValue = (BigDecimal)numFormat.parse(strToFormat, new ParsePosition(0));

System.out.println("Value : " + yourValue);
```

Result :

```
Value : 25.10
```

Comment: That will format 25 to "25,00"

Comment: Yes, this is not correct.

Comment: Test edited and result added after running the code